# Make a function accept std::initializer_list<T> and any iteratable type

Tags: c++

I want a function that can accept both an initializer list `{"a", "b", "c"}` and a `vector<std::string>` at the same time.

What I'm currently doing is this:

```cpp
void eats_ranges(const std::span<std::string>& values) {...}
void eats_ranges(const std::initializer_list<std::string>& values) {...}

int main() {
  eats_ranges({"a", "b", "c"});
  std::vector<std::string> vec = {"d", "e", "f"};
  ears_ranges(vec);
}
```

Can I simplify this somehow so that i only have one function for both or is it fine to have one extra function for `initializer_list`?

I've also tried `std::ranges::input_range` and `std::input_iterator` stuff but to no avail.

Comment: How about template? `template<typename T> void  eats_ranges(const T& values) {...}`?

Comment: @MarekR You can't pass a braced list to one, since it has no type.

Comment: OP, I think it's as good as it gets.

Comment: I would recommend to provide all possible usages. Also body of function is important, since then it will be clear if template is overkill or not.

Comment: I'd probably have one `eats_ranges_impl` with the body, and then have two `eats_ranges` that simply redirect to the same impl http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57b93a8bc04b2141

Comment: In this sample code, the `std::vector` is also a `std::vector<const char*>` and can't be passed as a `const std::span<std::string>&` either :(

Comment: yes, i fixed that. It was supposed to be a `std::vector<std::string>`